# Ejecutar una clase de Aplicación de consola en Windows Form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

tengo un programa en el cual fue programado en Aplicación de Consola y lo convertí en Windows Form. En el Program.CS remplaze el main y agregue lo siguiente:

```
    using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using YGOPro_Updater;

namespace YGOPro2_Updater
{
    internal class Program
    {   [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new VisualUpdater());
        }
    }
}
```

y lo que ejecutaba los comandos de la aplicación de consola la pase a una nueva clase llamada "Updater.CS"
Dejo el pastebin para que no sea tan largo:[Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/fyr8QREN)

Luego cree el Windows Form y un boton pero quiero ejecutar lo que hacia antes en la aplicacion de consola pero desde windows form pero no logro hacerlo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La clase estática Console no funciona en una aplicación Winforms. Lo que pasaste a tu clase Updater sigue llamando a métodos estáticos de la clase Console y no te va a funcionar. Aparte, tu clase Updater tiene un método llamado Command que recibe los argumentos pasados por el sistema, y no veo en que parte de tu código estés llamando ese método.

Comment: @Luis Entiendo, soy muy nuevo en Visual studio(C#), pensaba que podría ejecutar lo que hacia antes que era abrir el cmd y descargar desde repositorios de Github, pero lo que quería hacer era agregar algo mas bonito y poner un Form y un botón para cuando clickee ese botón ejecute la consola.

Comment: Si se puede, simplemente tienes que repensar como sustituir las llamadas a los métodos estáticos de Console con cosas de Winforms, por ejemplo, si antes mostrabas mensajes con Console.Writeline ahora puedes sustituirlo con Messagebox.Show("mensaje a mostrar", "título");

Comment: Ahhh que tonto soy, también puedo hacerlo en un Label que vi un tutorial hace poco, me voy a poner a jugar con el código, muchas gracias por la idea.